# SQL Server Create rows in 3rd table based on columns in 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a SQL Server newbie.  I am trying to create test data.

I have a table that contains 10,000 part numbers(Table1).

I have another table that contains warehouses(Table2).

I have a third table(Table3) that will contain a row for every part number/warehouse combination.

Table1 will contain the part numbers, Table2 will contain the 6 warehouses and Table 3 will have a row for each part number/warehouse. That means I will end up with 60,000 rows in Table3.  I have looked through all the JOINs and can't seem to find one that does the work.  What I want to do is load Table3 with all the part number/warehouse rows with a starting value of 100 in a column called On_Hand. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: `CROSS JOIN` maybe? Question is unclear.

Comment: Thank you both for the input.  Cross Join was the trick.  I had not seen the Cross Join in my previous research.                         INSERT INTO ProductWarehouses(ProductID, WarehouseID, OnHand, FreeStock)

SELECT pc.ProductID, w.WarehouseID, 100, 100

FROM ProductCodes AS pc (NOLOCK)

CROSS JOIN Warehouses AS w (NOLOCK)

Comment: Why `NOLOCK`? You know what that does, right..?

Comment: Well I was taught to use NOLOCK when doing a query and did not want to lock up the row the data came from.  I will certainly do some study to see when it makes since.  Actually thank you for raising the issue.  Like I said I am a newbie and willing to learn.

Comment: There's rarely a good reason for `NOLOCK`. People who advise on its use to "stop or avoid locking" are normally ill-advised. There's a lot of information on the query hint, it would be good for you have a research. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_3 ( Part_No, Location)    
SELECT Part_No, Location from InventoryTable CROSS JOIN LocationTable WHERE
       order by Part_No
```

Comment: Assuming that the table definition of TABLE_3 includes a default value of 100 for the On_Hand column... Bob's your uncle.

Answer (score 0):

Generate some data:

```
DECLARE @partNumbers TABLE
(
    PartNumber INT
)

DECLARE @warehouses TABLE
(
    Warehouse VARCHAR(20)
)

DECLARE @partNumberStart INT = 100

-- partnumbers 10000 starting at @partNumberStart  -- for testing.
 INSERT INTO @partNumbers
        SELECT @partNumberStart + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS ID FROM
       (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) x1(x),
       (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) x2(x),
       (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) x3(x),
       (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) x4(x)

--Warehouses 6 generated for testing
INSERT INTO @warehouses
        SELECT x1.x + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS ID FROM
       (VALUES('Warehouse ')) x1(x),
       (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5)) x2(x) --6
       --(VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) x2(x), --10
```

Query the data:

```
SELECT * FROM @warehouses LEFT JOIN @partNumbers on 1=1

--OR
SELECT * FROM @warehouses CROSS JOIN @partNumbers

--OR
SELECT * FROM @warehouses, @partNumbers
```

Answer (score 0):

You want `cross join`, used like this:

```
insert into inventory (part_no, warehouse_id, on_hand)  -- table_3
    select p.Part_No, w.warehouse_id, 500
    from Parts it cross join  -- table_1
         Warehouses w;        -- table_2
```